# PowerShell iterate through array of objects and find one

Tags: powershell

I have an object in PowerShell returned by VSTS which looks like this (!important: there is no @{ around these items as edited by Tomalak):

```
  @{
    objectId="ae97aa664f6c0cf803790a1fad78fc43119c6b8a"
    gitObjectType="tree"
    commitId="696e3462ef20058c4f3183d28568196d30f7e18f"
    path="/"
    isFolder=True
    url="https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_apis/git/repositories/11f25afb-4130-499b-ae49-d3fe24b0fadb/items//?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
  },
  @{
    objectId="e12eb8bd619733492279a8f8c8e0de99378dd299"
    gitObjectType="blob"
    commitId="696e3462ef20058c4f3183d28568196d30f7e18f"
    path="/Hello.ps1" 
    url="https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_apis/git/repositories/11125afb-4730-119b-ae49-d3fe24b0fadb/items//Hello.ps1?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
  },
  @{
    objectId="a4579b63a5cf68ca6a95937d56f15bac47a4f768"
    gitObjectType="blob" 
    commitId="696e3462ef20058c4f3183d28568196d30f7e18f"
    path="/README.md"
    url="https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_apis/git/repositories/48f25afb-4730-499b-ae49-d3fe24b0fadb/items//README.md?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
  },
  @{
    objectId="46e9b94f49b5a687c889f451c3a9b315e6044b7c" 
    gitObjectType="blob"
    commitId="696e3462ef20058c4f3183d28568196d30f7e18f"
    path="/file.txt"
    url="https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_apis/git/repositories/11f25afb-4130-499b-ae49-d3fe24b0fadb/items//file.txt?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
  }
```

It is saved in the variable `$xmlDataRepo`. When I do

```
$xmlDataRepo | ForEach-Object {
    write-host $xmlDataRepo.value.commitId
}
```

I get (!important, those values are really getting written in on single line in the PowerShell window!):

```
696e3462ef20058c4f3183d28568196d30f7e18f 696e3462ef20058c4f3183d28568196d30f7e18f 696e3462ef20058c4f3183d28568196d30f7e18f 696e3462ef20058c4f3183d28568196d30f7e18f
```

which looks good. But what want to do is find the object with the `path=/file.txt` and then get only this objects `objectId`.

I have tried it with this but it does not work:

```
$filename = "file.txt"

ForEach-Object -InputObject $xmlDataRepo.value -Process {
  if ($xmlDataRepo.value.path -eq "/$filename") {
    $oId = $xmlDataRepo.value.objectId
  } else {
    $oId = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  }
}
```

What is wrong here?

**Update 1:**

I have tried now the following code:

```
$xmlDataRepo | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.value.path -eq "/$filename") {
        write-host $_.value.objectId
    }
}
```

i have also tried

```
$obj = ($xmlDataRepo | Where-Object { $_.value.path -eq "/$filename" })

if ($obj) { 
    $oldId = $_.value.commitId
} else {
    $oldId = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

This is the object when i debug. But i always get 4 values (!) instead of only the one where the filename equals the filename in my variable.

[image]

I have also testet Santiagos solution like

```
$objectId = ($xmlDataRepo | Where-Object { $_.value.path -eq "/$filename" }).value.objectId
write-host "---$objectId"
```

But this also gives me four elements instead of a single one.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to match [mcve] rules. In particular, there is totally unclear how the `$xmlDataRepo` variable is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me now:

```
$xmlDataRepo.value | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.path -eq "/file.txt")
    {
        $oldId = $_.commitId
        $changeType = "edi“
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Where-Object instead of iterating yourself. See below.

```
$filename = "file.txt"
$objectId = ($xmlDataRepo | Where-Object { $_.value.path -eq "/$filename" }).value.objectId
```

Comment: No, does not work. I have also edited again my question due to edits by Tomalak, which could be misleading. Please try with my input again.,

Comment: Try with my latest edit, I had assumed from the object you gave that `path` was directly accessible.

Comment: I have upudated my question with new test results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$xmlDataRepo | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.value.path -eq "/$filename") {
    $oId = $_.value.objectId
  } else {
    $oId = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  }
}
```

Comment: No, does not work. I have also edited again my question due to edits by Tomalak, which could be misleading. Please try with my input again.

Comment: Please explain why it doesn't work. Does it give an error?

Comment: I have upudated my question with new test results.